# How to build iOS app extension with shell command and provisioning profile specified

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, xcodebuild, ios-app-extension

I have Xcode project which contains the app and app extension. I need to build **only the app extension** from command line in release mode for **production**. Currently for **development** I am able to build the extension with this shell command:

*In Xcode project(myproject.xcodeproj) **Automatically Manage Signing** is enabled before I run this command

```
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -scheme "myextension" -configuration "Release" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=./Products
```

It is successfull and I got **myextension.appex** in Products. App is also built which is not needed but that is not problem.

Now I want to build my extension for production, so it will need **production provisioning profile**. I have downloaded production profiles( **ProvisioningProfileApp** for app and **ProvisioningProfileExtension** for Extension). So from the shell command I need to specify that my extension need to use  ProvisioningProfileExtension and the app need to use ProvisioningProfileApp.

I run this commnad:

```
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -scheme "myextension" -configuration "Release" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=./Products APP_PROFILE=PATH_TO_APP_PROFILE.mobileprovision EXTENSION_PROFILE=PATH_TO_EXTENSION_PROFILE.mobileprovision
```

But I got the same output as previous. The provisioning profiles specified in the second commands are not used. Do I need to create separated Xcode project which inside will use this 2 profiles and use this project when building for production and use the old project with auto signing for development?

Thanks in advance.